# How to check for an empty intersection of lists with Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, set-intersection

Below is my code attempt for trying to create and then check the intersection of two lists in Haskell. Can someone help me get it to run?

```
empty_intersection :: (Eq a_ => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
empty_intersection as bs = (true if ([x | x <- as, x  `elem` bs) else false)
```

Comment: `(Eq a_` should be `(Eq a)`

Comment: `… if … else …` is not Haskell syntax. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures

Comment: Big thanks to Lorenzo and @Robin-Zigmond for getting me on track with the syntax. There was one more error that had to be corrected as well as shown in the edit above but its working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You've basically got the right idea here, there are just a few slight issues:

- You haven't closed the brackets around the list comprehension, which results in a parse error.
- A list can't be used directly with `if`, since `if` only works with values of type `Bool`. You may perhaps be thinking of some other languages where lists/arrays are considered "true" if and only if they are non-empty - but Haskell does no automatic type conversions, so you have to explicitly check if the list is non-empty. The best and easiest way to do this is to use the `null` function (which takes a list and returns `True` if its empty, and `False` otherwise).
- As @Bergi pointed out (and I missed initially), you've got a typo in your `(Eq a)` constraint.
- The `if` statement is backwards. Python has the construct `x if (condition) else y`, but Haskell instead uses `if condition then x else y`. Also, although this isn't wrong, there's no need for it when your `x` and `y` are `True` and `False`, because the whole thing just evaluates to whatever `(condition)` is.

So the code should be:

```
empty_intersection :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
empty_intersection as bs = null [x | x <- as, x  `elem` bs]
```

Comment: Thanks @Netwave - I just copied it from the OP and didn't even notice that! I see the OP also corrected it though.

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

Your code will not compile because a list cannot be a boolean, so you cannot have it in an if statement. There are however functions like `all`, `any` and `null` that can take lists and return booleans.

### Solution

Just use the Prelude function `null :: [a] -> Bool` which returns true if your list is empty. (Also note as @Bergi said you have a typo in your type constraint)

```
empty_intersection :: (Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
empty_intersection as bs = null [x | x <- as, x  `elem` bs]
```

### Even better

Also, as it's your second question on set unions and intersections, note that there is a library `Data.Set` for dealing with ordered sets which has much more efficients functions for intersection, union, membership, difference, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`intersect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect)

```
empty_intersection :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
empty_intersection = null . intersect
```